# Kendo setup on mvc4 vs2012

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

How can i setup kendo ui with mvc4. I want use its themas and grid and all controls  in my web application.

I have use http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html but how do i apply generated themas in my website. I am little bit confused with kendo, I am new with it. Please suggest me how can I configure kendo on mvc4 and use its all functionality.

Using : - MVC 4 , html 5 and c#

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

> How can i setup kendo ui with mvc4

In exactly the same way you would set it up with PHP. Or with a Java Servlet. KendoUI is a client side framework which is server side agnostic. It doesn't matter which server side technology you are using.

> I want use its themas and grid and all controls in my web application.

Great, go ahead. Head over to the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/changes-and-backward-compatibility), read it, roll up your sleeves and integrate into your application.

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using the Empty template
2. Add a HomeController to serve up a view:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```
3. And of course a corresponding `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view:

   ```
   @{
       Layout = null;
   }

   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <title>Index</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
       <input id="dropDownList" />

       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $("#dropDownList").kendoDropDownList({
               dataTextField: "text",
               dataValueField: "value",
               dataSource: [
                   { text: "Item1", value: "1" },
                   { text: "Item2", value: "2" }
               ]
           });
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

As you can see there's absolutely nothing MVC specific here. You could have served this markup from any server side framework. All you need is pick a theme, reference it from the Kendo CDN, reference the Kendo scripts at the end of your DOM from the CDN and start playing with it.

But the most important thing if you want to have some progress is to [`RTFM`](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/changes-and-backward-compatibility) where the guys from Telerik (and colleagues of mine) have spent a lot of time to documenting everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on the Kendo Docs site that will walk you through it step by step.

[Hello Kendo UI - Add Kendo UI](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Hello%20Kendo%20UI/asp-net-hello-kendo-ui-part-1#add-kendo-ui)

and

[Kendo Music Store - Project Setup](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Kendo%20Music%20Store/Music%20Store%20Web/kendo-music-store-web-setup)